# How to split a predicate with arity 6 into multiple predicates with arity 2?

Tags: clingo

I am very new to clingo and ASP. Any pointers will be appreciated!

I am trying to write a program for a scheduling problem. The input I will be getting is :

```
person(id, employee_type, max_workload, previous_workload, payment).
```

I want to split this into multiple predicates like:

```
employee_type(person_id, type)
max_workload(person_id, workload)
```

etc. in clingo.

I can easily define employee_type as:

```
{emp_type(EID, (f;c)}:-emp(EID).
```

where `f - full time ; c- contractor.`

But in case of workload, payment, the only condition is that this will be a positive integer.
How do I define these predicate?

I have multiple hard and soft constraints based on the values of workload, payment and employee type.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. To split a single predicate into multiple predicate :

```
emp_type(EID,ET) :- person(EID, ET, _, _, _).
max_workload(EID,MW) :- person(EID,_,MW,_,_).
```

etc.